# How can I prove that it is not a perfect square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, square-numbers

1. A $10$-digit number has one $1$, two $2$'s, three $3$'s and four $4$'s as its digits
   in some order. Prove that it can never be a perfect square.

Comment: It helps us to know what you have tried.People will feel more inclined to help you then.

Comment: I'm sorry , i'm actually new here. Anyway, I tried to add all of them as Nicolas below said, but I cant solve it. Permutations are not working. I cant approach the question in a correct way. That's why I asked for help.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50540/questions-on-perfect-squares?rq=1) might give you some further understanding of the problem.

Comment: @rah4927, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The digit sum $30$ is divisible by $3$ but not by $9$. So our number is divisible by $3$ but not by $9$, and therefore cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: why can't it be a perfect square if it's divisible by 3 and not by 9? Is there a proof to that statement?

Comment: @AnishBhattacharya,Just think about it for a while.Since the number is divisible by 3,it must be of the form $3k$. What happens when you square it?

Comment: Here is a proof. Suppose that $n=m^2$ and $3$ divides $n$. Since $3$ is prime, and $3$ divides the product $m\times m$, it follows that $3$ divides $m$. But then $9$ divides $m^2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I get it now. that's a rigorous proof. I hope I didn't waste both of your time. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. It is a complete proof if (as is likely) you have proved already in your course that if $n$ is a non-negative integer written in decimal form, then the remainder when you divide $n$ by $9$ is the same as the remainder when you divide the digit sum of $n$ by $9$. Or more weakly $n$ is divisible by $3$ if and only if the digit sum is, and is divisible by $9$ if and only if the digit sum is.

Comment: Anish, this may help: Write out any number with 1 ones, 2 twos, 3 threes and 4 fours. Verify that it is divisible by 3 and not 9. Now since the number is divisible by 3, its square root should also be divisible by 3. But if the square root is divisible by 3, the number should be divisible by 9 but you know it is not. Hope this long explanation helps